# Php foreach from Database in correct order

Tags: php, database, foreach

what could cause the issue that my foreach does not echo the user of my database in the correct order (like the order in my database?

My basic foreach looks like this:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
     echo $user[username];
}
```

Comment: Show me your database query that bring all users

Comment: Yeah, reason can be your query, probably you just need add "ORDER BY" in it...

Comment: Add double quotes for the name of fields ('username')

Comment: check by query and found the issue, I had a random in it, my bad but thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

change

```
echo $user[username];
```

to

```
echo $user['username'];
```

You can verify the exact key values using:

```
 print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the problem with your query.
you try **SQL ORDER BY** in query. It sorts the records in ascending/descending order by default.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have any idea of how your database is made, and also you haven't shown us the query you use to select your data I will try to explain you how to select data in the order you want/need.

Let's suppose your table is `MyUsers` and contains the following columns:

- MyUserID
- Username

If you want to select data ordered by ID just use the following query:

`SELECT * FROM MyUsers ORDER BY MyUserID`

In the `PHP` code you will have something like this:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
   echo $user['Username']; // Ordered by ID
}
```

If you want to order them by username just:

`SELECT * FROM MyUsers ORDER BY Username`

`PHP` will be the same but this time values will be ordered by the username (A-Z).

**NOTE:** It's always good to use an ORDER BY in queries since we cannot rely on default row order.

For further information, especially if you're new to SQL/MySQL I recommend you to give a look to the following links:

- [MySQL SELECT Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)
- [MySQL Sorting rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Good luck and I hope this helped you!